# Rails - attribute is not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
 if request.post? and @user.save
      @contact.user_id = @user.id
      @contact.save
      flash[:notice] = l(:e_user_saved)
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
 end
```

But when rails saves the contact, the user_id remains null.

When I debug I see that it assigns the value, but when it saves it saves null. Why???

Comment: Do you mean it's `nil` in the `contact`, the `user`, or both? What database are you using? Is it set up to autogenerate an `id` (primary key) on record creation>

Comment: What does `save` return? Replace it with `save!`. Maybe validations fail

Comment: how your Contact and User models look like ?

Comment: in contact model have u created any attr_accessor, attr_reader or attr_writer for user_id?, if so remove them.

Comment: `@contact.user = @user` should work. And try it from the console if in doubt. (or even better: write a test to check if `@user`, `@contact` are assigned correctly and whether adding the user to the contact works after that is sorted out).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it fails! thanks. But how does it save all other attributes? maybe there is another save? or what?

Comment: @NoamB.: what other attributes? You're assigning only `user_id`. What validation fails, with what message?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Contact has city and it fails.

Answer (score 1):

`contact.save` probably failed.  You're not checking the return value, so you don't know.

Check the `contact.errors` hash to see what went wrong.

You should probably have `contact.save` in an `if` block:

```
if @contact.save
  flash[:notice] = l(:e_user_saved)
  redirect_to :action => 'list'
else
  # some error handling
  # and redirect somewhere else
end
```